# Every row in a grid has a button, how can you find out the row of the button that was clicked

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

In LightSwitch, in the details section of a Master/Detail screen,
there's a grid that displays, let's say "Products".

I've made it so that the last column of each row contains a button.

The code behind generated by lightswitch look like this:

```
partial void DoSomething_Execute()
{

}

partial void DoSomething_CanExecute(ref bool result)
{

}
```

Inside these methods, is there a way to find out exactly which button was pressed (ie the button in which row)

Please note, the answer is not .SelectedItem() as you can press the button of any row in the grid without having to select that row first.

Update:

While I have now taken a different approach to display the data to the user,
I still would like to know the answer, so a bit more information:

[image]

(Sorry for the language, the customer doesn't speak English)

If you click on one of the buttons, the item in that row does become the SelectedItem
just as Michael said. That solves the (non)issue with the _Executed handler, but it still
doesn't allow us to put logic in the _CanExecute() handler that needs to know to which item the button is bound.

```
partial void DoSomething_CanExecute(ref bool result)
{
    result = !SelectedItem.IsClosed;
}
```

This simply updates all the buttons to the same state whenever a row is selected (obviously).

I'm wondering if there's a solution for this?

Comment: Side note: The idea of the button here was that it can only be used once, so now when the user closes the issue (presses the button) it is simply removed from the grid, which is a valid solution. Later I'd like to replace the button with an image button.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button that is in a row on the default LightSwitch datagrid, that row becomes the "selectedItem". see:
[List Box That Can Be Ordered By The End-User](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/90/List-Box-That-Can-Be-Ordered-By-The-End-User.aspx)

Comment: If in the Can_Execute handler you specify   result = !SelectedItem.IsClosed; (not real code) and you select a row where the .IsClosed property is true, all buttons are disabled. So the problem remains...

Comment: Can you explain more? I do not understand what you mean by "all buttons are disabled"

Comment: I think the problem you are having is that you want to know what row the button is bound to not what row is selected (because the row is only 'selected' when someone click on it). If you use a Silverlight custom control you can easily handle this (see: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/86/Help-Desk-An-Advanced-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-Application.aspx) I have no examples for doing this with the defualt LightSwitch grid.

Comment: I've got the same problem Timothy faced. I'd like to set the status of each button of my detail grid rows once i select my parent object. Here instead i have to use SelectedItem but changing the status of that property affects the status of each button in my details grid. Any improvement to this?